# How to work with config.json?

Tags: json, config

I have simple setup (from deskshell) where i have an
app.js with

```
var config = require('htdocs/js/config.json');
```

and config.json

```
    {
    "NAME" : "Scanner 2015",
    "LOGO" : "logo.gif"
}
```

and in index.htm i am trying to use logo.gif by

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#logo').attr("src", config.LOGO);
```

but logo.gif isn't loaded, hence config.LOGO doesn't work.

I assume the variables configured in config.json are ready to be used in index.htm?

How can i fix this??

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is good. The possible issue could be the path to your image or the access to your config variable.

```js
var config = {
  "NAME": "StackOverflow",
  "LOGO": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png"
}

$(function() {
  $('#logo').attr('src', config.LOGO);
  $('#text').html(config.NAME);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="logo" />
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: going with your solution and converted config.json to just a regular config.js

Comment: There's also json plugin for [require](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) but it depends on your real needs.